# How to handle captured dynamic value which is keep on changing their position in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I captured a dynamic value , but that value position is keep on changing on each running. how to handle it.

```
  Ex:
        Daysrpc61_g1=68
        Daysrpc61_g2=98
        Daysrpc61_g3=107
```

Here i need 98 which potion is _g2, but this position will change in next run.
Please help on this how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) configuration vague, i.e. if you're not interested in `68` and `107` you should amend the extractor logic to return only one value.

Also be aware that in general [using regular expressions to parse HTML responses is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), you should be using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) or [Xpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)/[XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a better regular expression extractor to successfully find your value. 
Google **online regex tester** and you'll find many good sites which will help you adapt your regEx to fit exactly and solely the case you want.